# Uncountably many subgroups of an abelian group

Tags: group-theory, abelian-groups

Does the abelian group $\mathbb{Z}[\frac{1}{2}]$ have uncountably many subgroups?

Comment: What does the notation $\mathbb{Z}[\frac{1}{2}]$ mean?

Comment: @m.k.: It means that we take the subring of the rationals $\mathbb{Q}$ generated by $\mathbb{Z}$ and the element $\frac{1}{2}$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No. The strict subgroups are of the form $a\cdot 2^m\mathbb Z \; (m\in \mathbb Z \;,\; a\in 2\mathbb N+1)$.

[Core of proof: look for  elements in the subgroup with smallest possible power of two ($=m $) . If there are  some  take the one with least positive possible odd $a$. Else the subgroup is not strict.]

Comment: You need to combine the two descriptions, $\frac{a}{2^m}\mathbb{Z}$ for non-negative odd numbers $a$ and integers $m$ are all distinct proper subgroups.  In other words, 1/2 is not in the subgroup { (3n)/2 : n in Z } which is closed under addition. (negative m give the subgroups of Z).

Comment: About Georges's answer and Jack's comment: It suffices to show that the proper subgroups are cyclic.

Comment: Dear @Jack:  you are absolutely right and I have now edited my  answer. Thanks a lot for spotting and correcting my former erroneous statement.